# how to add multiple command to start nodejs app on window

Tags: node.js, windows

I am trying to setup a node js app by following [link](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html)

On windows it say run -

> set DEBUG=myapp:* & npm start

and I get the following error

```
At line:1 char:20
+  set DEBUG=myapp:* & npm start
+  ~ The ampersand (&) character is not allowed. The & operator is reserved for future use; wrap an ampersand in double  quotation marks ("&") to pass it as part of a string.
+ CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmpersandNotAllowed
```

Now I changed "&" to "&&" which throw an error - "The ampersand (&) character is not allowed. The & operator is reserved for future use; wrap an ampersand in double 
quotation marks ("&") to pass it as part of a string."

so I changed to

> set DEBUG=myapp:* "&" npm start

```
Set-Variable : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'npm'.
At line:1 char:2
```

Please let me know if anyone knows how to solve this.

Comment: What version of windows are you on? & and && work just fine on my Windows 10 machine. Also, are you using cmd.exe or a third party app.

Answer (score 0):

This is may be because of widows version problem,but you can run app by just writing following command also

```
npm start
```

and it works fine.